# Use of pushglobaltable and setfenv in Lua5.3

Tags: c++, lua

how to get luathread function with same function name in diffent luathreads in Lua 5.3? 
use getglobal in 5.1 work sucess, but under 5.3 work error,

this code is main run call luathread functions

```
const char * gLua0 = "function Test() print(12) end";
const char * gLua1 = "function Test() print(23) end";

lua_State * sL0 = newLuaThread();
luaL_loadbuffer(sL0, gLua0, strlen(gLua0), nullptr);

lua_State * sL1 = newLuaThread();
luaL_loadbuffer(sL1, gLua1, strlen(gLua1), nullptr);

lua_getglobal(sL0, "Test");
lua_pcall(sL0, 0, 0, 0);

lua_getglobal(sL1, "Test");
lua_pcall(sL1, 0, 0, 0);
```

//---- result of lua 5.1

12
23

//----- result of lua 5.3

23
23

why result 5.3 is diffent from 5.1?

this code is create lua thread in lua 5.1

```
lua_State * newLuaThread()
{
    lua_State * sL = lua_newthread(L);

    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    int nRef = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

    lua_pushvalue(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");

    lua_setfenv(L, -2);

    lua_pop(L, 1);
    return sL;
}
```

this code is create lua thread in lua 5.3

```
lua_State * newLuaThread()
{
    lua_State * sL = lua_newthread(L);

    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    int nRef = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

    lua_newtable(nLuaState);
    lua_pushvalue(nLuaState, -1);
    lua_setmetatable(nLuaState, -2);

    lua_getglobal(nLuaState, "_G");
    lua_setfield(nLuaState, -2, "__index");

    lua_setupvalue(nLuaState, 1, 1);

    lua_pop(L, 1);
    return sL;
}
```

Comment: `setuservalue` doesn't replace the use of function environments it replaces the user of userdata environments. The replacement for function environments in lua 5.2+ is [`_ENV`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.2).

Comment: thank you! i spend more time on setupvalue, but also not work

Answer (score 1):

spend 5 days find the correct answer is:

```
luaL_loadbuffer(nLuaState, nBuffer, strlen(nBuffer), nullptr);

lua_newtable(nLuaState);
lua_pushvalue(nLuaState, -1);
lua_setmetatable(nLuaState, -2);

lua_getglobal(nLuaState, "_G");
lua_setfield(nLuaState, -2, "__index");

lua_pushvalue(nLuaState, -1);
lua_setglobal(nLuaState, nChunk);

lua_setupvalue(nLuaState, -2, 1);

lua_getglobal(nLuaState, nChunk);
lua_getfield(nLuaState, -1, nFun);
lua_pcall(nLuaState, 0, 0, 0);
```